# Why is my Android Thread so Slow?

Tags: java, android, multithreading

I have been trying to write a poker scoring algorithm... which has seven nested for-loops to iterate through every combination of seven card poker hands and score them. It is of course a pretty intensive loop... with just under 110.5 million combinations.

My algorithm is a raw work in progress... but manages to correctly score all the hand combinations in about 8.5 seconds in Eclipse on my Desktop. Not bad I thought... but the same algorithm in an Android thread takes 17 minutes on the Android emulator and 4 minutes on my HTC One XL.

I was fully prepared for the phone to run slower than my newish desktop... but not by a factor of 30.

My code is below;

```
public void startThread() {

  Runnable runnable = new Runnable()
  {
    String bitString;
    byte[] bitCount = new byte[8192];
    byte[] isStraight = new byte[8192];
    boolean[] isFlush = new boolean[8912];

    int c, c1, c2, c3, c4, c5, c6, c7;
    int[] cards = new int[7];
    long sTime, eTime, score = 0;
    int[] handCount = new int[9];

    int pipMask;
    int[] pips = new int[6];
    int[] suit = new int[4];

@Override
public void run()
{
    for (c = 0; c < 8192; c++)
    {
        bitString = String.format("%13s", Integer.toBinaryString(c)).replace(" ","0");

    }

    sTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    pips[0] = 8191;

    for (c1 = 0;      c1 < 46; c1++) {
    for (c2 = c1 + 1; c2 < 47; c2++) {
    for (c3 = c2 + 1; c3 < 48; c3++) {
    for (c4 = c3 + 1; c4 < 49; c4++) {
    for (c5 = c4 + 1; c5 < 50; c5++) { 
    for (c6 = c5 + 1; c6 < 51; c6++) {
    for (c7 = c6 + 1; c7 < 52; c7++) {

        --- code goes here ---

    }}}}}}}

    eTime = System.currentTimeMillis(); Log.d("end", "" + (eTime - sTime));

    message = handler.obtainMessage();
    bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putString("msgText", "Finished in " + (eTime - sTime));
    message.setData(bundle);
    handler.sendMessage(message);

  } // end run()

}; // end runnable

Thread myThread = new Thread(runnable); myThread.start();

} // end
```

Am I doing something wrong with implementing Threads in Android?

I'm worried it may be the size of the byte and boolean arrays and some sort of memory limit imposed on the Thread?

Comment: Your phone probably *is* 30 times as slow as your desktop.

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with how you do it, and memory is definitely ok.  But a phone is a much lower resource device than a PC, and I'd be doubtful of even a PC being able to do this in seconds-  last time I wrote something similar on PC it took minutes to run.  If you want a speedup, you could partition the space and run N of these threads (where N is the number of cores in your phone).

Comment: You definitely should port this routine to NDK (c++) and access it from Java. As it just does calculations and doesnt mingle with the hardware, screen, etc... the porting should be nearly direct. Also, try to avoid any String (let alone REGEXes -- replace) operations inside long loops, they are terribly slow! If you decide to port to C++ it'd be cool if you post here the time differences.

Comment: You better install a server/webservice and send the configuration to it. The server calculates and sends a score as response.

Comment: This is basically a static list of data once calculated, right? Why not just compile it into a SQLite database and do a lookup? Doesn't seem to be any reason why every client would need to do the calculations.

Comment: Thank you all. I was desperately hoping I was doing something wrong as the code is far too slow to be useful. With some minor tweaks I was able to get down to 130 seconds on the phone... but that's about it for my coding abilities.

Comment: A webservice is not where I can go... and the SQL database would be way too big and I imagine quite slow to make millions of queries. I might have to look at the c++ option... but it looks quite complicated to set up. I googled a couple of eclipse tutorials and they are a bit out of my league I'm afraid.

Comment: Maybe I'm misunderstanding, but you shouldn't need to make millions of queries. Just one query per hand to score. SQL is designed for large datasets.

Comment: Seven cards from a deck of 52 gives you 133 million plus different hands to score. That's a big database for a phone.

Comment: @rupps - Ok... it has taken the better part of three days to set up the ndk and get some code running (I'm a little bit out of my depth here - can't get logCat to work from c++ etc)... but the new native code (with some tweaking) now takes only 21 seconds on the phone!

Comment: hehehe cool!!! Nice to learn about the speed bost, 20 times faster is definitely something to have in mind for heavy calculations!

Comment: Down to 15 seconds or less now (peaks at over 12 million hands per second). :D

Answer (score 1):

The problem is not threads.

The problem is not memory usage ... because it looks relatively small, and (AFAIK) doesn't change in the part of your code where the work is being done.

The real problem is that you have a 7-level deep loop which a substantial range on each variable and you are doing a lot of work inside the loop.

(Hint: 46 * 47 * 48 * 49 * 50 * 51 * 52 ... is a rather large number.)

And basically, your PC can run Java code a lot faster than a typical mobile phone.  A factor of 30 is plausible to me.

---

One thing to take into consideration is that the JIT compiler in a HotSpot JVM is much more sophisticated and much more "aggressive" than a typical Android JIT compiler.  If anything, that is going to magnify the difference in hardware performance.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you all. Once it was clear that there was nothing inherently wrong with how I was using the thread in Android I took up rupps suggestion of porting the code to NDK/C++. It is much faster now; 21 seconds vs 240 seconds.

ie. more than 10x.

Still not fast enough to make for a useful app... but it's fun trying. :)

Comment: Ok... a late update... but with NDK I am now hitting over 12m hands a second (albeit on the latest HTC One M8). It runs through the 133m hands in less than 15 seconds!

Comment: And correspondingly I've been able to produce a (semi)useful poker app. Thanks for the suggestions!